# Detect frame drop in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

How can I detect a dropped frame in OpenCV?  Right now I am doing a check like the following:

```
int main() {
     VideoCapture cap(-1); 
     if (!cap.isOpened()) {
         cout << "Webcam is not open." << endl;
         return -1;
     }

     Mat frame;

     while (true) {
         cap.read(frame);

         if (!frame.empty()) {
             imshow("frame", frame);
         }
         else {
             cout << "No captured frame" << endl;
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

But I still get messages saying "Camera frame dropped!" without my "No captured frame" message.  What conditions result in the camera frame being dropped/how can I check for those conditions?

Comment: maybe that message is from the driver or some underlying library? Maybe your processing is slower than the fps of your camera? That could result in dropped frames (the requested frames are too old), where the camera just delivers a newer frame instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this opencv function cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) to obtain the presentation timestamp of a videoframe. This function returns an integer in multiples of time interval. If any frame drop, the timestamp would have skipped to (N+2)*time_interval instead of (N+1)*time_interval where N is your current frame number.